# Magento 1.x API V/s Magento 2.x API

Tags: magento2, api, magento-1, web-services

I have a project in which we are using Magento 1.4 API for mobile app now we want to migrate our platform to Magento 2.x .

My question is that what's different in Magento 2 API V/s Magento 1 API implementation has any one experience on this scenario help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

The API has been rewritten for Magento 2.  It is no longer held in separate classes.  Instead, already existing classes are used to fulfill the functionality of the API.  This way there is no code duplication, or discrepancy between core functionality and API functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Magento2 have absolutely different implementation than in M1, so it fully incompatible.

See [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, Magento 2 APIs are totally different from Magento 1 version. And, more flexible than M1.

Magento 2 API docs:

http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

https://alankent.me/2015/08/31/magento-2-rest-api-swagger-schema/